# Changed color settings of ble.sh bash terminal are not applied

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, git, colors

I installed the ble.sh from this git repository https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh.git, but i want to customize the color settings with `ble-face` commands.

What happens is that, I changed the color settings but when I close the terminal the changes are gone.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the settings of `ble-face` in `~/.blerc`. The color settings by `ble-face` are only enabled in the shell session where they are executed. It's just the same as other shell settings like aliases, functions, and environment variables, which should be put in `~/.bashrc` to make them persistent.

Comment: I've done it! Thanks.